# Insert a batch number into a table in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, count

I have a temp table where I insert modified data extracted from a SELECT query.

In this temp table I want to group my rows into batches, so I added an indexed INT column called "BATCH_NUM"

The idea that I am hoping to achieve is this (for say 1000 results in my SELECT statement).

Pseudo Code

```
Batch Size = 100
Count = 0
For batch size in results set
Insert Into Temp Table (a , b , y , count)
Count++
```

**Current SQL - inputs static value of 1 into BATCH_NUM column**

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE
(
  ASSET_ID,
  PAR_PROM_INTEG_ID,
  IGNORE
  BATCH_NUM
)
SELECT carelevel.row_id, pstn.PROM_INTEG_ID, 
CASE
    WHEN promoprod.fabric_cd = 'Disabled'
    THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END
'1'
FROM SIEBEL.S_ASSET carelevel
INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET pstn
ON pstn.row_id = carelevel.par_asset_id
INNER JOIN SIEBEl.S_ASSET promotion 
ON pstn.prom_integ_id = promotion.integration_id
INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT prod
ON prod.row_id = carelevel.prod_id
INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT bill
ON carelevel.bill_accnt_id = bill.row_id
INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_INV_PROF invoice
ON bill.row_id = invoice.accnt_id
INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT promoprod
ON promotion.prod_id = promoprod.row_id
WHERE prod.part_num = 'Testproduct'
```

But if the select statement has 1000 results, then I want BATCH_NUM to go from 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10 per 100 records.

Can this be done?

Comment: You want only the first batch -- or insert the following values as part of an other batch at the same time ? (say 1-100 => batch 1, 101-200 => batch 2)

Comment: Correct, incrementing batch num depending on result set / batch size

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To map record to batch, you might simply want to use integer division. Or slightly more complicated as row are numbered from 1, but something like `TRUNC((ROWNUM-1)/100)+1` will do the trick.

Here is a test for that mapping:

```
select level, trunc((ROWNUM-1)/100)+1 from dual connect by level <= 1000
```

Result:

```
ROWNUM  TRUNC((ROWNUM-1)/100)+1
1       1
...
100     1
101     2
...
200     2
201     3
...
...
900     9
901     10
...
1000    10
```

---

Given your query:

```
INSERT INTO TEMP_TABLE
(
  ASSET_ID,
  PAR_PROM_INTEG_ID,
  IGNORE,
  BATCH_NUM
)
SELECT carelevel.row_id, pstn.PROM_INTEG_ID, 
CASE
    WHEN promoprod.fabric_cd = 'Disabled'
    THEN 'Y'
    ELSE 'N'
END,
TRUNC((ROWNUM-1)/100)+1,
-- ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
-- map rows 1-100 to batch 1, rows 101-200 to batch 2 and so on
FROM SIEBEL.S_ASSET carelevel
INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_ASSET pstn
ON pstn.row_id = carelevel.par_asset_id
INNER JOIN SIEBEl.S_ASSET promotion 
ON pstn.prom_integ_id = promotion.integration_id
INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT prod
ON prod.row_id = carelevel.prod_id
INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_ORG_EXT bill
ON carelevel.bill_accnt_id = bill.row_id
INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_INV_PROF invoice
ON bill.row_id = invoice.accnt_id
INNER JOIN SIEBEL.S_PROD_INT promoprod
ON promotion.prod_id = promoprod.row_id
WHERE prod.part_num = 'Testproduct'
```